# HTTP2 Framing Errors on BBC servers when a cookies are present

Tags: networking, wireless, google-chrome

This is a **really** strange issue which sounds insane... hear me out:

When I'm logged to the BBC on Chrome OR Firefox nothing loads. No News, iPlayer etc. Firefox reports NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT. Chrome reports ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM.

When I'm logged out - i.e. delete my cookies - BBC websites work fine.

When I log in again the servers are unresponsive.

This problem occurs with different BBC Accounts.

This problem only seems to occur on the BBC.

This problem only arises on my home WiFi network. I've connected to my phone via tethering and the issue doesn't occur.

This problem only arises on Ubuntu. I've booted over to Windows and everything works fine.

This problem doesn't occur on other (Ubuntu) devices on my home network - my laptop etc all work fine.

This problem doesn't occur when I connect to my network via Ethernet.

This problem still occurs if I change my IP address on the network.

This problem still occurs if I connect to my router's guest WiFi network.

So the combination of this specific Ubuntu install, the specific WiFi network and the presence of cookies are causing the BBC servers to be unavailable somehow.

Does anyone have any ideas at all what could be causing this? I'm completely baffled.

Here's the cURL of two requests, one which works and one which does't, with my tokens redacted...

```
curl 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news' \
  -H 'authority: www.bbc.co.uk' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'cookie: ckns_explicit=0; ckns_policy=000; ckns_policy_exp=1692715113061; ckns_privacy=july2019; atuserid=%7B%22name%22%3A%22atuserid%22%2C%22val%22%3A%2257dcff47-1ed3-429a-bd77-9555363a544c%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%222023-09-23T14%3A38%3A33.079Z%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D%7D; ecos.dt=1661179121656' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

^^ This gets me the website correctly.

```
curl 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news' \
  -H 'authority: www.bbc.co.uk' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'cookie: ckns_explicit=0; ckns_policy=000; ckns_privacy=july2019; ckns_policy_exp=1692715164370; atuserid=XXX; ckns_id=XXX; ckns_atkn=XXX; ckns_idtkn=XXX; ecos.dt=XXX' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

This results in `curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer`

To be clear the second request works successfully when connected to a different WiFi network and when booted over to Windows instead of Ubuntu.

Anyone have any ideas at all? This isn't really a huge issue to be honest I'm just so absolutely confused by what's going on.

Thanks,